# if statement returning true

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why, when selecting a psd file, the if statement in the php code passes as true and echos "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop"?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES["myimages"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["myimages"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["myimages"]["name"][$key];
        $imagetype = $_FILES['myimages']['type'][$key];

        if ($imagetype == "image/jpeg" || "image/gif") {
            echo $imagetype;
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<? echo basename(__file__); ?>">
    <input type="file" name="myimages[]" multiple>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a general tip: you can enable inspections in most modern IDEs that will complain about bad conditions like `if ("foo") {` you will be forced to write `if ("foo" === true") {` (which is `false`) which makes it easier to spot these mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this is wrong

```
if( $imagetype == "image/jpeg" || "image/gif" ) { /*...*/ }
```

Should be

```
if( $imagetype == "image/jpeg" || $imagetype == "image/gif" ) { /*...*/ }
```

Or even

```
if( in_array($imagetype, ["image/jpeg", "image/gif"]) ) { /*...*/ }
```

---

That is, because non-empty string is considered true, so the IF condition was met.

Comment: Please also explain _why_ it returns an unexpected true.

Comment: Explanation: `if (anyCondition || "image/gif")` always returns true as `image/gif` is a non-empty string. I guess the OP thinks the `||` does something else.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to be first :P It's explained now

Comment: because anything that doesn't evaluate to 0 evaluates to true and "image/gif" is not 0 so if `$imagetype == "image/jpeg"` evaluates to false the expression will still return true because of what I already said.

Answer (score 4):

This is because bitwise operator has lower priority than equality check. It goes like this:

1. You have

   ```
   if ($imagetype == "image/jpeg" || "image/gif") {
   ```
2. Equality resolves to boolean first, and your expression becomes:

   ```
   if (false || "image/gif") {
   ```
3. Non-empty strings are treated like `true` when used in expression. That means we have

   ```
   if (false || true) {
   ```
4. And the result of this, of course, is `true`, so the if-block executes.

Answer (score 2):

Your || statement is incorrect

```
$imagetype == "image/jpeg" || 
$imagetype == "image/gif"
```

What's happening is "image/gif" is returning true and that true is being or'd with the false returned by 
$imagetype == "image/jpeg".  false || true == true

Answer (score 2):

You can also have the following condition :

```
if ( $imagetype == ("image/jpeg" || "image/gif") ) {
    echo $imagetype;
}
```

The other answers are good, this is just another way to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($imagetype == "image/jpeg" || "image/gif")
```

is equivqlent to:

```
$condition1 = $imagetype == "image/jpeg";
if($condition1 || "image/gif")
```

which will be evaluated **in this case** as :

```
if($condition1 || true)
```

which evaluates to **true** no matter what is the value of `$condition1`

because `if(false || true)` returns `true`

Another point: I suggest to use **===** operator instead of **==**, so your final code should be:

```
if($imagetype === "image/jpeg" || $imagetype === "image/gif")
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement as you wrote it would be expected to evaluate as TRUE.

This is because you're not comparing "image/gif" to anything, you're simply evaluating it as a boolean value. PHP converts string values (that are not `"0"`, or empty (`""`)) to TRUE when they're evaluated as a boolean. So, essentially, your IF statement is saying "if `$imagetype` is equal to `"image/jpeg"` OR `"image/gif"` is TRUE, then do this stuff.

Your if condition will always pass, because "image/gif" will ALWAYS be evaluated as true, so it doesn't matter what `$imagetype`s value actually is.